# counting character occurrence in input file

Tags: java

My program prompts the user to enter a specific letter and filename and then prints out the number of occurrences of the parameter letter in the input file.

Code I wrote:

```
public class CharCount {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        Scanner inp= new Scanner(System.in);
        String str;
        char ch;
        int count=0;

        System.out.println("Enter a letter: ");
        str=inp.nextLine();
        while(str.length()>0)
        {
            ch=str.charAt(0);
            int i=0;

            while (i < str.length() && str.charAt(i) == ch)
            {
                count++;
                i++;
            }
            str = str.substring(count);
            System.out.println(ch + " appears " + count + " in" );
        }
    }
}
```

I get this output

```
Enter a letter:
e appears 1 in
```

But I should be getting this output

```
Enter a letter: Enter a filename: e appears 58 times in input.txt
```

Any help/advice would be great :)

Comment: where do you input the file name in your code?

Comment: It's hard to describe this method, but try writing some more letters (different letters, not just one letter repeated) and enjoy. You'll get an increasing count for different letters, then it most likely dies with StringIndexOutOfBoundsException in the substring method. Funny.

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8, you can rely on streams to do the work for you.

```
String sampleText = "Lorem ipsum";
Character letter = 'e';
long count = sampleText.chars().filter(c -> c == letter).count();
System.out.println(count);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's give a start help:

```
   // Ask letter:
   System.out.println("Enter a letter: ");
   String str = inp.nextLine();
   while (str.isEmpty()) {
       System.out.println("Enter a letter:");
       str = inp.nextLine();
   }
   char letter = str.charAt(0);

   // Ask file name:
   System.out.println("Enter file name:");
   String fileName = inp.nextLine();
   while (fileName.isEmpty()) {
       System.out.println("Enter file name:");
       fileName = tnp.nextLine();
   }

   // Process file:
   //Scanner textInp = new Scanner(new File(fileName)); // Either old style
   Scanner textInp = new Scanner(Paths.get(fileName)); // Or new style
   while (textInp.hasNextLine()) {
       String line = textInp.nextLine();
       ...
   }
```

Comment: You're very kind. I'd rather recommend the author of the question to try some beginner tutorials than write code for him. Yeah, this should give him a kick start.

Comment: By the way, I haven't used `do-while` many times yet, but your code looks like just the perfect case - try using `do {...} while (str.isEmpty())`

Comment: @Vlasec Yes however I tried to answer in concepts that the OP already used - the answers till then where from java 8 streams to whatever. An idea for ross.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex.

Imports:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
```

Ex Usage:

```
String input = "abcaa a";
String letter = "a";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(letter, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE + Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

int i = 0;
while(m.find()){
  i++;
}
System.out.println(i); // 4 = # of occurrences of "a".
```

Comment: how would i add an input file ? like this ish ? inputStream = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

Comment: and do i have to import anything when using that ?

Comment: @ross.c i made some small changes to the coded and added a row for the imports.